# Launch android/ios activity form platform-specific code

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Flutter is a completely new technology for our team, and we have a project that we are going to write in flutter. We need functionality in our project, which is not available in "google_maps_flutter 0.0.3+3" at the moment, so we are thinking of making a part of the project with maps separately for android/ios and everything else in the Flutter. I was able to run native Android activity using the platform channels, but unfortunately our IOS developer is temporarily unavailable, and so I would like to ask, can I launch IOS native activity with the platform channels or maybe someone knows better solution for my problem.

Comment: Of course you can launch iOS native activity using platform channel, all you need to do is handle things in swift/objective C code.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/platform_view_swift) could be helpful.